# NuGet custom repositoryPath working but can't build

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore

VS 2015 with Update 2.

I have a nuget.config file next to my VS 2015 solution file and I have configured repositoryPath to a folder 2 levels up from the solution file.  VS downloaded/restored all packages fine but when I expand References, all are displayed with warning icon and projects won't build with

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ...

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if packages are removed and added back then everything would work again. Either manually or by running `Update-Package -Reinstall`.

Bug reported on https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2830